# Flash script setTimeout in actionscript 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs5

The "loopCount" variable is not functioning in the below code.

```
       stop();
       this.gotoAndPlay(2);

       if (!loopCount) {
         var loopCount:Number = 0;
       }
       loopCount++;

       if (loopCount < 2) {
          _global["setTimeout"](this, "gotoAndPlay", 4000, 4);
          this.stop();
       }else{
          this.gotoAndPlay(122);
          var loopCount:Number = 0;
       }
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. In what way is `loopCount` not functioning? What values do you expect it to have and how does it differ when you debug your code?
2. If you're going to a new keyframe with your calls to `gotoAndPlay()` then Flash will reinitialise your variables on that new keyframe.
3. Why are you setting a timeout in this section of code?:

   _global["setTimeout"](this, "gotoAndPlay", 4000, 4);